# how can I upload a 4 multi index level row hierarchy from excel into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I spend hours trying to find a solution but nothing so far.
I have the following table (see screenshot).
can anybody please shed some light and explain me how to upload it into a dataframe?
Many thanks,
Andrea

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttnHC.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
pd.read_excel('data.xlsx', header=[0,1], index_col=[0,1,2,3])
```

Comment: it works! Omg, I think I spent hours trying to find this solution. Thank you! May I ask, from a python beginner point of view, why index_col=[0:3] doesn't work?

Comment: [0:3] is not a python list.   type that on a line by itself and it will not return [0,1,2,3].  It is a slicing operator that works on a list.  You might try range(0,3).   I am on my phone so I dont know for sure if that will work.  Would you accept this answer if it helped?